# SQLite installation problems

Tags: sqlite

I downloaded the binaries for windos for sqlite and extracted them. There were three files

1. a shell
2. dll
3. analyzer

when I try to run to create a database and a  table from the `sqlite` shell i get....

```
  SQLite version 3.7.8 2011-09-19 14:49:19
  Enter ".help" for instructions
  Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
  sqlite> sqlite3 test.db
  ...> create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
  Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error
  sqlite>
```

when I try to run to create a database and a  table from the **command line(Vista)** shell I get....

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6000]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\codenamejupiterx>sqlite3 test.db
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\codenamejupiterx>
```

does anyone have any ideas?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the command `sqlite3 test.db` to start the sqlite shell.  (your first example) From in there, you do not need that part of the command again, just issue the "create table " command.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "installation".

The error is that "sqlite3.exe" was not found in the search path as defined by the [(Windows) PATH environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Either add it to `%PATH%` (see [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)) or use a complete file qualification that does not rely on `%PATH%`. A fully qualified invocation may look like:

```
C:\path\to\sqlite\sqlite3.exe test.db
```

Running sqlite3 by "double clicking" the executable in Windows Explorer **is the same as above** [as it uses an absolute path to run the sqlite3 executable] -- albeit without the ability to specify the database name or other options. (These can be specified in a "shortcut" to sqlite3, if desired.)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for the link and advice but i have a few more questions.  Item 4 in the article states:
    In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of   the      class to the value for PATH.                                                               Would the class be in the dll file, the shell file or theanalyzer file?

Comment: @codenamejupiterx Add `C:\path\to\sqlite` (the directory where sqlite3.exe lives, but not the executable itself) to the %PATH% variable. I forgot that link was so Java-biased! Make sure to separate it from the other entries with a `;` and *do not* add any extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe And sqliteadmin to open sqlite database

Regards